# Are there in Russian any inanimate masculine nouns ending on -a?

Tags: грамматика, существительные

Are there any Russian inanimate masculine nouns ending on -a?

I can think of many feminine ones (машина, ангина, книга, панорама, перспектива, etc.), but are there any masculine ones?

Comment: @elDude: the op is asking for inanimate nouns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only marked ones, formed with suffixes *-ина* and similar: *домина*, *голосина*, *дождина* etc.

Comment: @brilliant: can't find it, but I distinctly remember this question had been asked before

Comment: Do you think all your examples belong more to the shared gender (общий род), rather than strictly to masculine? I can say "Этот домина просто поражает", but at the same time I can't say "Ненавижу этот домина" and would rather say "Ненавижу эту домину". Same with "голосина" and "дождина". No?

Comment: @brilliant: this paradigm is marginal, so grammar sense might fail the native speaker.  Major dictionaries list *домина* as masculine, so while both *ненавижу этот дождину* and *ненавижу эту дождину* might be used in spoken language, only the former is correct in standard language. *Домина* can be easily confused with *домовина* ("coffin") which is feminine, so this could also lead to a contamination.

Comment: I personally would never ever say "Ненавижу этот дождину" - something in me just doesn't sit right with that.

Comment: Ушакова. *Словарь трудностей русского языка для школьников.* **Домина** — , -ы, **м. и ж.** `Вот и домина богатая. Кладите меня лицом к востоку. [В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 5-8 (1913-1932)]` `Сама же домина была приземиста, как бы сплющена. [Олег Павлов. Казенная сказка (1993)]`

Comment: @brilliant: this "something" is your innate habit of using 1st declension nouns in sg. acc. with *эту* (feminine) or *этого* (masculine animate) only. As I said, inanimate masculine nouns in *-a, -я* are very rarely used.

Comment: @Avtokod: in the first sentence it's obviously "coffin", a contamination with *домовина*.

Comment: @Quassnoi no =)

Comment: @elDude: yes. Thanks for valuable input, though.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Do you have any quotation, in which any such noun would be used in the accusative with the pronoun этот right before it?

Comment: @brilliant: _Да за такой домину где-нибудь в Малаховке заломили бы тысяч шестьдесят. // Евпланов А. Я., "Чужаки", 1990_

Comment: I wanted "этот", not "такой". Google gives me only nominative cases.

Comment: Oh, I already found some.